# Can Webassembly Module be serialized?

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, encoding, webassembly

Is it possible to serialize a WebAssembly module ? Like [this](https://github.com/OmkarAcharekar/Serialize_and_Deserialize_DataStructure).
I find out that it is implemented [here](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasm-c-api/blob/c9d31284651b975f05ac27cee0bab1377560b87e/example/serialize.c#L54-L63) . But I didn't got the full implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the serialized form of a WebAssembly module is defined in a standardized manner in the WAsm spec: https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/bikeshed/#binary-format%E2%91%A0 .

A web browser receives a WAsm module in the serialized format.

Comment: Hi @Nick, Actually I am looking for [this](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasm-c-api/blob/c9d31284651b975f05ac27cee0bab1377560b87e/example/serialize.c#L54-L63) type of serialization  . I want to know the implementaion of  serializing a module into vector of bytes

Comment: Can you show me any project where it is actually implemented?

Comment: I think you're looking for https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/ca3220c64954260da79d23c8566ec5e9dbe57f96/src/wasm/wasm-serialization.cc ?